# Protecting/Encrypting Software Data

Tags: windows, encryption, video, authorization

I've tried to find the answer for days from many sources, but unfortunately not reached any solution.

The problem is how to prevent user from accessing to software data (videos, images, etc.). For example, i have a software or mobil application. And it has some folders that contains videos. I don't want users not to access directly and copy them.

In addition, since these files are big, any conversion of the file needs much time. So this causes slow down the application. I think, encrypting the whole file takes a long time.

I'm asking my question independent of any environment. It can be a windows or android application. Is there any method or technic to achieve this?

Edit: If there is a way to decode/encode the files quickly, it can help me. Or such a password protection solution...

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Not really. All you can do is obfuscate the files, and (on mobile) you have limited resources with which to do this (cpu,ram)

No matter what you do to the files, your program must contain all the information required to decode them or they will not be usable. Ergo, the determined attacker will be able to get the files.

If all you are trying to do is keep out the casual person, then you probably don't need to do anything - extracting files from within mobile applications is generally beyond the normal user.